# Does TypeORM supports raw SQL queries for input and output?

Tags: orm, typeorm

I would like to know if there is a feature of TypeORM that supports raw sql queries for Insert Update Delete Select etc..

Answer (score 71):

According to this issue [comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/235#issuecomment-307711542), TypeORM enables you to use any queries to your heart's content. using `entityManager.query()` Here is the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api).

**UPDATE**

Link above is outdated, try this instead [entity-manager-api](http://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api).

```
const rawData = await manager.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS`);
```

Comment: The link to doc above is broken / has changed. Current url: http://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api

Comment: The api documentation is all of one line. What is the syntax for passing in parameters?

Comment: @OldGeezer it depend to what database you are using. An example for mysql can be found on this link https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/881#issuecomment-329364169

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I forgot to mention it's MySql I am using. So I see it is just `?` by position.

Comment: Another related question: the returned result from a `Query` is of type `OkPacket`. I Googled and only *one* page was found and it's not related to typeorm. Do you know where I can find more information on `OkPacket`?

Comment: Be aware that the link on github is an early version of of typeorm instead do: `const rawData = await manager.query("select id, email, name from users where id=?", [id])`

Comment: The structure of `rawData` is an array of `object` with each prop set to the column name. I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 28):

2020 UPDATE, entityManager.query() basing the entityManager off the EntityManager class, was not working for me so had to do this:

```
  import { getManager } from 'typeorm';

  const entityManager = getManager();
  const someQuery = await entityManager.query(`
  SELECT 
    fw."X",
    fw."Y",
    ew.*
  FROM "table1" as fw
  JOIN "table2" as ew
    ON fw."X" = $1 AND ew.id = fw."Y";
  `, [param1]);
```

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/working-with-entity-manager

Comment: I think you have missed to await before entityManager ?

Comment: Is there a way to grab tableName from the entity, instead of supplying it directly (which will break if table name changes)?

Answer (score 20):

try out this (April, 2022, typeorm ^0.3.6)

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

(async () => {
    const AppDatasource = new DataSource({
        type: "mysql",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3306,
        username: "root",
        password: "root",
        database: "your-database",
        synchronize: false,
        logging: false,
        entities: ['src/entity/**/*.ts']
    })
    const appDataSource = await AppDataSource.initialize();
    const queryRunner = await appDataSource.createQueryRunner();
    var result = await queryRunner.manager.query(
        `SELECT * FROM your-table LIMIT 100`
    );
    await console.log(result)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *deprecated getConnection* or repo instance:

```
const db = this.repo.manager; // or getConnection().manager

const users = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM "users";`);
const [{ total }] = await db.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM "users";`);
// users.length === Number(total);
```

> Metadata allows you to get table properties dynamically

```
// utilities...
const usersTableMeta = db.connection.getMetadata(UserEntity); // or getConnection().getMetadata(UserEntity);
const usersTable = `"${usersTableMeta.tableName}"`

// data...
const users = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM ${usersTable};`);
const admins = await db.query(`
    SELECT id, name FROM ${usersTable}
    WHERE ${usersTable}.role = 'admin';
`);
```