# typeorm add index on jsonb column property

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have a table which has a `jsonb` column named `asset`. The record in this column has a field called `value`. I am looking for an option to create index of `asset.value` but unable to find it. Can someone help me out here? I am using `typeorm`.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with doing what you're asking, but I did find [this article](https://scalegrid.io/blog/using-jsonb-in-postgresql-how-to-effectively-store-index-json-data-in-postgresql/#6) about GIN Indexes.  So if you have this table

```
CREATE TABLE test(id int, data JSONB, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

you can create a GIN index on it:

```
CREATE INDEX datagin ON books USING gin (data);
```

It doesn't look like TypeORM will support this type of specialized index at the moment. See [this github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1519).  But you could add the `CREATE INDEX` and `DROP INDEX` manually to a TypeORM migration `up()` and `down()` function.

Then you'd also need to run custom SQL to make use of the index with the **Path Operators @>, <@**:

```
select * from books where data @> '{"braille":true}'::jsonb;
```

Which you can do [with the EntityManager API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493554/does-typeorm-supports-raw-sql-queries-for-input-and-output):

```
const rawData = await manager.query(`select * from books where data @> '{"braille":true}'::jsonb`);
```