# Correct use of LEFT JOIN/ON/AND on TypeORM from a PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Im trying to convert this query made it on postgreSQL to TypeORM

My PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT project.status.name, COUNT(project.case."statusId") AS status
FROM project.status
LEFT JOIN project.case
    ON project.case."statusId" = project.status.id AND
       project.case."userId" = 1
GROUP BY project.status.name;
```

The result of the query returns me the status with values and also values with zero:

```
statusName    count
   Open         1
  Closed        0
```

I have this on typeORM but this returns me only the status that have a value on it and I want to return also the status with zero value.

```
const totalCases = this.caseRepository.createQueryBuilder('case')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('case.status', 'status')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('case.adminUser', 'adminUser')
  .select('status.name')
  .addSelect('COUNT(*) AS count')
  .where('adminUser.user = :id ', { id: userId })
  .groupBy('status.name')
  .getRawMany()
return totalCases
```

And I get this:

```
[
    {
        "status_name": "Open",
        "count": "1"
    }
]
```

But I need this:

```
[
    {
        "status_name": "Open",
        "count": "1"
    },
    {
        "status_name": "Closed",
        "count": "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You have a fine clearly readable and working query in a standard declarative language. Why not [run it natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493554/does-typeorm-supports-raw-sql-queries-for-input-and-output) but replace it with a smudged and cryptic proprietary syntax?

Comment: Because Im working with TypeORM on NestJs and I have my database on PostgreSQL. So I tried the query on PostgreSQL first and then Im trying on TypeORM because I was using this to everything on my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start from the `statusRepository`, just as the `FROM` clause of your query starts with `project.status`:

```js
statusRepository.createQueryBuilder('status')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('status.cases', 'case')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('case.adminUser', 'adminUser')
  .select('status.name')
  .addSelect('COUNT(*) AS count')
  .where('adminUser.user = :id ', { id: userId })
  .groupBy('status.name')
  .getRawMany();
```

Perhaps you first need to define `cases` inside the `Status` entity to be the inverse side (`@OneToMany`) of the `@ManyToOne` from `Case.status`.

The problem you ran in is if there is just no case with a certain status, you will never join this status with `case LEFT JOIN status`. Thus all your rows with `count = 0` will not appear if you start with the case and not the status.